# How to render e grid-based form with Symfony Form component?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have `Grid` model in a one-to-many relationship with `GridElement`s. A `GridElement` has the following structure:

```
<?php

class GridElement
{
    /** @var Grid */
    private $grid;

    /** @var Column */
    private $column;

    /** @var int */
    private $row;

    /** @var string */
    private $value;
}
```

The `$column` is a many-to-one relationship with a `Column` model. The thing to know here is that when I want to create or update a `Grid`, its columns are fixed: one can only add or delete rows.

Now I want to use Symfony Form component to be able to edit my Grid, and more specifically its elements.

My issue is about the HTML rendering. I need an HTML like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Line 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[0][columnId]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[0][row]" value="1">
            <input type="text" name="elements[0][value]" value="A1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[1][columnId]" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[1][row]" value="1">
            <input type="text" name="elements[1][value]" value="B1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Line 2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[2][columnId]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[2][row]" value="2">
            <input type="text" name="elements[2][value]" value="A2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[3][columnId]" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="elements[3][row]" value="2">
            <input type="text" name="elements[3][value]" value="B2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is no problem to generate something like this and have it all working out if my grid is empty to begin with. Just some JavaScript code to generate new rows and delete others, nothing hard here.

The part I can't figure out is how to generate something like this when my form has some elements in the first place? I can create a template to define what the rendering of a `GridElement` should be (ie. the `<td>` part with the 3 inputs in it), however I don't see how I can arrange my `GridElement`s in rows.

Should I just loop through my elements and generate the form without any of the form rendering functions? This way I would be able to implement my own logic to know where to start a `<tr>` and when to end it. Error messages won't be a problem because if there's an error in a cell, the message will be on the on the *elements* path, not the specific element one.

Or is there a fancier way I cannot see?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CollectionType with prototype.
This work with jQuery and you can custom item as you want. Not simple, but works great.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype